# Abrir Bat como administrador desde linea de comandos del propio Bat

Tags: cmd, batch

Es posible que el bat se autoejecute como administrador sin necesidad de hacer click derecho y ejecutar como administrador?

He probado con:

```
Runas /user: %computername%\admin
```

Pero pide contraseña, es con el comando RunAs pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Comment: prueba `runas /user:Administrator /savecred comando.exe` , si no recuerda la clave a la segunda vez tal vez haya que tocar la politicas de equipo o de la cuenta admin

Comment: Me sigue pidiendo contraseña. "Escriba la contraseña para Administrator:" Lo raro es que si en vez de Administrator pongo cualquier otra cosa inventada me sigue pidiendo la contraseña para dicho usuario inexistente.

Comment: microsoft la complica con varias cosas, fijate en el registro la clave `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\disableddomaincreds`  si está a 1 ponela a 0. si eso no funciona tendrías que entrar al policy manger y buscar la opción

Comment: Tiene que ser usuario Administrador sí o sí? O valdría con cualquier usuario "tipo Administrador" con permisos elevados?

Comment: Aunque no lo he probado, he visto esta página, donde parece que se resuelve: http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/windows/ejecutar-aplicacion-en-windows-como-administrador-sin-escribir-contrasena/734